# What is user agent ;__CT_JOB_ID__:?

Tags: web-crawlers, user-agent, botattack, spam-bots

I've been searching the web for an explanation of the sudden influx we've gotten of user agents of this format:

`;__CT_JOB_ID__:68a72eee-353c-4b0b-82ae-0cb6c8ca3e6e;`

Each visitor has a unique IP. So far the range includes: `66.196.82.*`, `67.195.61.*`, `74.6.40.*` and `98.139.190.*`

Do we know why type of user this is? I'm particularly interested in knowing it if its a bot. It seems to primarily be coming through our Google Ad Display channels and always has a `gclid` set (which means we are paying for this traffic).

Research hasn't come up with much yet, I've looked at these other reports online:

`https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/Unknown-Browser-Name-in-Browser-and-OS-Report/td-p/1729159`

`https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/Weird-browser-values-in-GA-report/td-p/1723798`